How to sort the singleSelect column in MUI X Data Grid
Im using mui x grid and trying to sort singleSelct column, it has three values accepted rejected or pending. the field name is status. i tried sortComparator but give undefined value to callback. while it was expected some value to make sort logic.
what is missing here. I followed the doc and also a stack answer but it could not help me to fix my issue.
code:

function DataGridDemo() {
...
  const columns = [
    ...simpleColumns,
    {
      field: 'status',
      headerName: 'Status',
      width: 120,
      type: 'singleSelect',
      editable: true,
      renderCell: (params) => <StatusControl ... />,
      sortComparator : (x)=>{
        console.log({x}) //  undefined x
        return 0
      }

    },
  ];



  return (
    <Box sx={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>

      <DataGrid
        apiRef={apiRef}
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        loading={isLoading || rows.length === 0}
        initialState={{
          pagination: {
            paginationModel: {
              pageSize: 5,
            },
          },
          sorting: {
            sortModel: [
              {
                field: 'status',
                sort: 'asc',
              },
            ],
          }
        }}
        columnVisibilityModel={visibleColumns}
        onCellEditStop={(e)=>{
          console.log('edit stop '.e)
        }}
        pageSizeOptions={[5]}
        checkboxSelection
        disableRowSelectionOnClick
        
        onRowSelectionModelChange={(params) => {
          setSelectedRows(rows.filter((row) => params.includes(row.id)));
        }}
        slots={{
          footer: CustomFooterStatusComponent,
        }}
        slotProps={{
          footer: { 
            ...
          },
        }}

      />

    </Box>
  );
}

export default DataGridDemo;

